# Can'r run ASP.NET Core app on AWS EC2 Ubunti

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

Tried many step-by-step guides, but still unable to run a very simple ASP.NET Core 5.0 on Ubuntu Linux 20.4 from AWS EC2

What I did:

Configured Inbound rules for the instance:

80  TCP 0.0.0.0/0

80  TCP ::/0

22  TCP 0.0.0.0/0

443 TCP 0.0.0.0/0

443 TCP ::/0

Installed Dotnet SDK on instance

Installed NGINX

Configured NGINX with these settings

```
server {
listen        80;
server_name   localhost;
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

}

This syntax of config file is correct

Reload NGINX

Status of NGINX is Active/Running

When I run the application it show this

[image]

So, it shows that it is Ok and listening to 5000/5001

And finally when I try to access instance in the browser by ip like this:

http://33.333.333:80

in the console I see this:

[image]

but app is not coming in the browser - i see ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT and page is redirected to https://3.33.33.333:**5001**/

In Startup.cs in Configure method at the very beginng I have this:

`app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions { ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto });`

So, request from browser definately reaches the server, but the rest is not working.

Which step am I missing?

Comment: It is not clear from the question, whether a request to https://33.333.333:443 reaches your app. Did you configure firewall to allow connections on port 5001? What is the output if you attempt 'wget https://localhost:5001' from the console on the server?

Comment: @AlexeyAdadurov Thanks for your reply. 
Guides that I followed didn't mention firewall configuration - I just configured Inbound rules for EC2 instance for 80/443 ports.

Comment: When I run from the server's console both wget https://localhost:5001 I see this 
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5001... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify localhost's certificate, issued by ‘CN=localhost’:
 Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to localhost insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

Comment: Let's set the certificate issue aside for a while... Let's use the suggested option --no-check-certificate and see what happens.

Comment: Oh, and where is the proxy config rule for passing connections from port 443 to 5001 where your app is listening for secure connections?

Comment: @AlexeyAdadurov, so if I run wget 'localhost:5001'

I got this

--2021-05-17 18:13:28--  http://localhost:5001/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5001... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

Comment: @AlexeyAdadurov and if I run wget https://localhost:5001 --no-check-certificate

I have this

Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5001... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify localhost's certificate, issued by ‘CN=localhost’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html

Comment: @AlexeyAdadurov I tried to make a clean experiment - Created new Asp.Net Core application and disabled HTTPS be default - and it works. So, it's definately HTTPS issue

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your goal is to enable HTTPS/TLS access to he app. There are 2 levels of the response I can provide:

- Without nginx everything would work fine on ports 5000 and 5001. This is confirmed by the results of your attempt to run `wget https://localhost:5001 --no-check-certificate`, which was successful (except for certificate trust issue).

So to run the app without nginx, it seems to be enough to change the ports to 80 and 443 in your ASP.NET Core config file and solve the TLS certificate trust issue. To learn more about development certificates, you should refer to Microsoft Docs for information about [development certificates for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos). At the same time, from the question it looks like you need to refresh the general theory on HTTPS, TLS and certificate trust questions.

- For some reason, you'd like to include nginx in the setup. In this case your need to consider the below items:

1. Potentially reconsider your design choice: which component (nginx or app) is responsible for redirecting users from port 80 to port 443? This can be done on nginx and will remove this concern from your app.
2. Enable proxying the requests from port 443 to 5001 in nginx config file.  The nginx.conf file included in your question don't include necessary directives.
3. Configure a trusted TLS certificate using the nginx config file. The question of trust is a broad one and the answer depends on the goals of the deployment that your are creating. Is it for development, testing or production?

Comment: thanks a lot again for your detailed question

I decidede to have both Kestrel and Nginx for my app, cause it is recommended by Microsoft itself. I just follwed guide in this case (btw, all tutorials highly recommend to have both Kestrel and Nginx). That's why I was surprised that I had (and still have) this issue with certificates which is not highlited in any tutorial and which was supposed to be in a working state by default

Comment: And again, non of these tutorials mentioned something like "Enable proxying the requests from port 443 to 5001 in nginx config file. The nginx.conf file included in your question don't include necessary directives.
Configure a trusted TLS certificate using the nginx config file."

Comment: And this is for production, for sure

Comment: A public production site on the Internet needs a publically trusted certificate. You dont create these on your own machine, b/c otherwise there would be no way to prove a trust relationship. For an intranet site, a certificate can be created by an internal CA, because the certificate only needs to be trusted by internal systems where IT department can manage trust. Please check out this guide: https://geekflare.com/tls-101/amp/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help